# Methods in the Hiredis.h that are not defined

Tags: redis, hiredis

I have just started using hiredis as a c client to connect to redis for my c project in visual studio. Therefore, please pardon me if I seem to be unknowledgeable.

Basically, the problem I have is I download the hiredis source from here: https://github.com/redis/hiredis/releases and tried to compile and run with some of the examples here: https://redislabs.com/lp/hiredis/. However it seems like there is an error saying some methods example `sdsempty()` in the 'hiredis.c' file is not defined. Am I missing a step of making files or installing the hiredis library? I am very clueless right now and will appreciate any help I can get. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you find and answer yet? I'm having the same issues.